# Calling a jQuery function from a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

I am having problems trying to activate a jQuery function from a PHP.

The following is my own test version.

### index.php file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Welcome to temp index</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min[2].js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            //posts info into the userinfo.php file
            $.post('userinfo.php', { activate:"colourchange"}, function(data){
                $('report').html(data);
            });

            //the function which is meant to be activated from the php file
            function colourchange(){
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';   
             };         

         }); 

    </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello</h1>

<div id="report">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

### PHP file I am attempting to call my jQuery function from

```
<?php

if( $_REQUEST["activate"])
{
  $activate = $_REQUEST['activate'];
};  

if($activate == 'colourchange') 
{
 // This is the code that I believe not to be working as this isn't 
 // activating the jQuery function to work. (The page background isn't changing colour)

    echo "<script>colourchange(); </script>"; 
};

?>
```

Thank you to anyone who has an idea of what to do it is much appreciated.

I have now tried ...

```
<?php
require 'userinfo.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Welcome to temp index</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min[2].js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function colourchange(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';   
  };



  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('userinfo.php', { activate:"colourchange"}, function(data){
      $('report').html(data);
    });    
 }); 


</script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello</h1>

<div id="report">
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

and the PHP index file is ...

```
<?php


if( $_REQUEST["activate"])
{

  $activate = $_REQUEST['activate'];

};  




  if($activate=='colourchange')
  { 
    echo "colourchange();";
  };

?>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Is the request variable set? Have you checked?

Comment: The above is the complete code so to my knowledge I haven't set a request variable.

Also as far as I'm aware the part that isn't working is actually calling the jquery function from the php file however many threads have told me to use the following ...  

    echo "<script>colourchange(); </script>";

But this doesn't seem to be calling the function for me weather it is a alert, colour change, sound etc.

Comment: What do you mean by „calling a function from a PHP file“? Do you mean, that the PHP script directly calls the javascript function?

Comment: I would like the PHP file to tell the Jquery file to start a function and do what ever that function is asking.

Comment: So the php code is not inside of your `index.php` but in another file?

Comment: ye the PHP code is in a different file

Comment: just to note... it is wrong to think that the php is calling the function. php is just parsing the function. it is the browser that executes it

Comment: You should just have the PHP file return a piece of JSON, or even like a 1 or 0... Then check the result, an run that function in your success callback for the $.post. There's no reason to have the PHP script send back HTML with a script tag with JavaScript in it.

Comment: Is the main purpose for this code just to set a color on body when page is loaded? What's the point of calling php at all?

Comment: Mixing PHP and JavaScript probably isn't your best bet. You'll probably be better to use AJAX to ask PHP for something and then use the result to update the client.

Comment: @AdamWaite - op is actually using ajax (through jQuery's $_POST - function which is a shorthand for $_ajax...)

Comment: It is AJAX, but not quite the common technique. But if the plan has to be to fetch JavaScript, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ might be a good method to use

Comment: oops, I didn't read the code ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why you are using PHP to execute a jQuery function at all - perhaps this is just an oversimplified example. Assuming your primary goal is to have the PHP response trigger a specific Javascript function (and perhaps allow for the PHP response to trigger several different responses) you'd do something like this:

First change the callback from

```
function(data){
  $('report').html(data);
}
```

to something like:

```
function(data) {
  if (data.indexOf("colourchange") >= 0) {  // php page returned "colorchange" or a string containing "colourchange" 
     colourchange();
  } else if (data.indexOf("moodchange") >= 0) {
     moodchange();  /// etc... you can add more trigger functions here
  }
}
```

And second... just have your PHP page return "colourchange" instead of an HTML snippet:

```
if($activate == 'colourchange') 
{
  echo "colourchange"; 
};
```

Does that help?

Comment: jo jo that didn't work however that is very interesting so using something such as 
    var colourchange = (data);

    if(colourchange == "colourchange"){
    colourchange();
    }

I'm not sure how quite to write this as my head is just not in gear currently

Comment: it works thank you jo jo i had tooo many })'s lol thanks soo much

Answer (score 0):

you could try this-- example call the jquery function on success

```
  $.ajax({
     url: //the url,
     data: //the data,
     type: "POST",
     success: function(data){

         if(data == "ok"){
        colorChange();
        }
     }
   });
```

here the data will be the success result returned by the php code..

you can call a function depending on the data returned